# css 3 float issue

Tags: css, layout, xhtml, css-float

i have three float, which i need it in three div, cause the top float is dynamic like youtube expand videos option. anyway following are three float, two are on left and one one right, the right float only goes on second float right, but does not move more above that.

```
<center>
<div style="width: 1024px;">
    <div style="width: 100%;">
       header content here..
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div style="width: 630px; float: left">
        video here...   right float should show next to this box, sence this is below the header...
    </div>

    <div style="width: 630px; float: left">
        comments here and other options...
    </div>

    <div style="width: 230px; float: right">
       related videos here..   (this box goes above and touchs the comment area only, but does not go all the way up to video area, what im doing wrong? btw i cant put comment and video in same div, because of some dynamic feature.
    </div>
</div>
<center>
```

Note: i cant change the div orders...

Comment: What does "the right float only goes on second float right, but does not move more above that" mean?

Comment: What is the width of the parent div that has the three floated divs inside it? By the looks of it your page should be around 1500px wide to let all the three floated divs sit next to each other.

Comment: sorry, i cannot answer this. my crystal sphere is downstairs. Could you try to be a little more precise?

Comment: The `<center>` will not hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<center>

    <div id="wrap" style="width: 1024px;position:relative;">

        <div id="header" style="width: 100%;">
       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..       header content here..
        </div> <!-- END OF id=header-->

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <div id="leftColumn" style="width: 630px; float: left;">

            <div id="video">
                video here...
            </div>

            <div id="comments">
                comments here and other options...
            </div>

        </div> <!-- END OF id=leftColumn-->

        <div id="rightColumn" style="width: 230px; float: right;">
       related videos here..   (this box goes above and touchs the comment area only, but does not go all the way up to video area, what im doing wrong? btw i cant put comment and video in same div, because of some dynamic feature.
        </div> <!-- END OF id=rightColumn-->

    </div> <!-- END OF id=wrap-->

</center>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/borayeris/tDdvA/